# How to get the last five working dates from the current date in pyspark databricks?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I want to get the last five dates from the current date excluding Saturday and Sunday. For example, today's date is 4 May 2023 (Thursday) then the last five working days will be 28-Apr(Fri),1-May(Mon), 2-May(Tues), 3-May(Wed), and 4 May(Thur).  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to get all five values in 1 cell in a table or what? You could use `dayofweek("date").isin([1,7]).cast("int"))` to check if a date is Saturday or Sunday. The `dayofweek` function will return a number between 1 and 7 (Sunday = 1, Saturday = 7).

Comment: @ASD, what databricks are you using? aws/azure or community edition?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, from your question I am not sure exactly how and where you want those days. Here however is how you can display them in a simple dataframe:

`from pyspark.sql.functions import current_date, col, when, date_format


number_of_previous_days = 5
WEEKENDS = ['Sat', 'Sun']
previous_days = current_date() - col("id").cast("Int")

select_previous_weekdays = when(~date_format(previous_days, format='EEE').isin(WEEKENDS), previous_days)
df = spark.range(number_of_previous_days + 1).withColumn("Previous_weekdays", select_previous_weekdays)`

That would give you a dataframe with columns id and Previous_weekdays, now if you do not want id or null values you can also do

`df.select("Previous_weekdays").where(col("Previous_weekdays").isNotNull()).display()`